# Is it legal to work as a student assistant in Germany if I'm a student in Italy?

Tags: germany, europe

So I have a long residency in Italy and I'm finishing my masters, but I found a good thesis in Germany and they offered me while doing the thesis to work as a student assistant (to be able to cover my fees there)

Is this legal to me? The HR department is not being clear or helpful much.

EDIT: I am an Italian resident.  I have a student residency for a year and it can be renewed for every year I study here

Comment: Are you an Italian or EU citizen? The headline suggests you are but “long residency” suggests you are not.

Comment: If the OP is not an EU Citizen, then probably [§16c - Mobility of students (AufenthG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0294) applies.

Comment: What do you mean by "long residency in Italy"? Because you question says you are a student in Italy. Either you have temporary residence in Italy or you have "LTR" (Long Term Residence), also known as permanent residence. And then in your question you are talking about being a student in Germany. It is confusing.

Comment: I updated the question to answer all the questions